# Anyway to accelerate multi-screen 4k H265 decoding on laptop without ExpressCard/ThunderBolt?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I recently need to do some 4k video editing on my Dell XPS 13 (2015 model). The computer has an i7 5500U CPU with integrated graphics and no PCIe-based port. The only connection option is USB3.0.

I connected a 4k TV and an HD monitor to it via the display port and a DisplayLink USB3.0 adapter respectively. I notice GPU usage reaches 100% when video is playing on the TV but dies down to an acceptable level if I disconnect the USB adapter. Obviously my GPU is not powerful enough to run both.

I am wondering is there a way to add a external graphics card or HEVC decoder to it?

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Unless you are willing to tinker with your motherboard, which you say has no PCIe, there is absolutely no way to add an external graphic card to a system. This is due to the fact that PCI offers huge bandwidths unlike other connections (e.g. USB). Thus the processor and other peripherals can never communicate fast enough over other such buses.

So unless you have PCI, its a no-go for you.

Another Point: Don't bother much about 100% GPU usage unless it really heats up to shutdown, as these systems were designed for this.